# Trigger a Jenkins job depending on two conditions

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins that installs and configures a program after the build.
The problem I have now is that it is dependent on that both server and Client have been built.
Earlier they were built in a specific order, so I could trigger my job on the last built.
From now on I cannot know which one is built first so I need something else to trigger my installation.
My first thought is to have the build jobs creating a file and name it depending on if the other job already have created a file or not. But I thought I should ask here first, as I think it should be possible to do this easier and less error prone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) which will trigger a job when all the immediate downstream jobs have completed. You may need to then configure one parent job which will trigger the downstream jobs.

Comment: I like the Join plugin. And with what I wrote it should work. So I set this as a solution.
The problem for me is that it is another system that handles the upstream stuff and I have no control over them. So the Join plugin do not work in this case. So I created files that my installation job is polling for.